# Does the Life Cleric's Disciple of Life feature affect spells that use the target's Hit Dice? (e.g. Wither and Bloom, Catnap)

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting

Considering the feature from life domain cleric, disciple of life.

> Disciple of Life:
> your healing spells are more effective. Whenever you use a spell of 1st level or higher to restore hit points to a creature, the creature regains additional hit points equal to 2 + the spell's level.

Considering the spell Wither And Bloom.

> one creature of your choice in that area can spend and roll one of its unspent Hit Dice and regain a number of hit points equal to the roll plus your spellcasting ability modifier.

Is the healing from the hit diced considered as a result of the spell, thus triggering disciple of life ? Or is it only a result of the creature's own "rest" ?

On a side note. Considering the spell catnap.

> If a target remains unconscious for the full duration, that target gains the benefit of a short rest

It seems to me that the creature is not taking "a short rest", but only getting "the same benefits as a short rest", which includes healing. Healing coming from the spell. Do you think this is RAW ?

Comment: @biziclop [Please do not write answers in comments](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533/should-users-refrain-from-answers-or-partial-answers-in-comments).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Disciple of Life works for both of these

Disciple of Life triggers "[w]henever you use a spell of 1st level or higher to restore hit points to a creature". Both these spells are spells, and both cause the target to regain hit points. These spells are unusual because the number of hit points regained depends on the target rather than the caster, but that does not matter for Disciple of Life.

The counter-argument would be something like, "it's not the *spell* that's restoring the hit points, it's just that the spell did something that had a side effect of allowing the target to restore hit points to *themselves*". This argument is somewhat plausible at first glance (more so for Catnap than for Wither and Bloom), but ultimately, I don't buy it. The target has more hit points because of the spell. They would not have those hit points without the spell. Therefore, the spell restored the hit points.

#### But...

If the target does not spend any Hit Dice (because they do not have any left to spend, or because they simply choose not to), then they do not get the bonus healing from Disciple of Life. The spell has not actually restored any hit points in that case, and they cannot "[regain] **additional** hit points" if they did not get any in the first place.